# php form validation and header location

Tags: php, forms, validation, header

I have a form submitting to intself. If the post variables are set, then I want them to be redirected to **employee_profile.php**. Currently the header  location does not work even when the post variables are set. Any ideas?

```
<?php 
    $email_error = $password_error = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $email_error = "Missing Email";
        } else {
            $email = $_POST["email"];
        }

        if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $password_error = "Missing Password";
        } else {        
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];
            header ('Location: employee_profile.php');
        }
    }  
?>
```

The form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $email_error;?></span><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="password">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $password_error;?></span><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the code corresponding to the form too ?

Comment: <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">

Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $email_error;?></span><br />

Password: <input type="password" name="password"><span class="error"><?php echo $password_error;?></span><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

Comment: Errr, add it to the original question, don't post it as a comment!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP header (using HTTP/1.1) redirect requires an absolute URL.

Try the following:

```
<?php 

// from PHP documentation, see http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// or:
// $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$email_error = $password_error = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Missing Email";
    } else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $password_error = "Missing Password";
    } else {        
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }

    // some additional fixes: finally check if both is valid
    if($email_error == $password_error) {
        header("Location: http://$host/employee_profile.php");
    }
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing like this. currently in your script even when the email is not set but password is set, header function is called.

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : "Missing Email";
$password = (isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password']   : "Missing Password";

if($email != "Missing Email" && $password != "Missing Password"){
    header ('Location: employee_profile.php');
}
```

(warning: here any values passed as email and password will get the user to employee_profile)

also see if you are printing some thing or some htmls before calling header.

is it throwing any error, if so can you also print the error here?